# How to set default value of the date to be next Saturday in the datefield?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

How to set the Value and minValue property to be the next Saturday in the following code?

I want in the datefield, the default display date to be saturday's date. Let's say today is 08/09/2018 and the default value display should be 08/11/2018. You can run the below code in Sencha fiddler:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
      value: Ext.Date.add(new Date, Ext.Date.DAY, 6), // defaults to today
      minValue: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, 6),
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You would need to add a lot more context to your question to get a decent response. Please look into Sencha Fiddle and maybe add a demo of what you are trying to get to.

Comment: I have added the detail. please help on this. thank you.

Comment: Did my answer help? Ware you able to do what you wanted?

Comment: Hi Akrion, thank you so much. Yes it did help. Is there any way I can put this function and variable inside this Ext.Create object because I am not creating object of it in the application but just defining like Ext.define('Ext.form.Panel', {...... –

Comment: @Akrion, please let me know once you get a chance. I am waiting for it to have function and variable define inside Ext.define{.... class because this Ext.Create (....... is just for the Sencha Fiddle purpose only to show here only. But I am defining it  as Ext.define('Ext.form.panel', {.... blah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version of something like this:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',
  launch: function() {

    function getNextDayOfWeek(date, dayOfWeek) {
      var resultDate = new Date(date.getTime());
      resultDate.setDate(date.getDate() + (7 + dayOfWeek - date.getDay()) % 7);
      return resultDate;
    }

    var nextSaturday = getNextDayOfWeek(new Date(), 6)

    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      width: 300,
      bodyPadding: 10,
      title: 'Date',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        value: nextSaturday,
        minValue: nextSaturday
      }]
    });
  }
});
```

You can see it in action [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kau). The key is the `getNextDayOfWeek` function which comes from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/find-next-occurring-friday-or-any-dayofweek).

Comment: Hi Akrion, thank you so much. Is there any way I can put this function and variable inside this Ext.Create object because I am not creating object of it in the application but just defining like Ext.define('Ext.form.Panel', {......

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kau see this. You can have it outside the app or in another file if you want.

Comment: What about inside the file? Because I am just loading up this class without initializing.

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516310/how-to-use-global-functions-utility-class-in-extjs. Define this function in a `util` class and then use it as shown there.